# Strike through text After Effects CS6

Tags: after-effects

In most Adobe CS6 apps, the character palette has a strikethrough button. In After Effects CS6, this seems to be  missing.

Is there a way to do strikethrough in After Effects CS6. Most the tutorials I have searched for show how to do animated strikethroughs. I just want a simple text strikethrough (without animation) <del>like this</del>.

Comment: You are right, there is no functionality in the *Character Panel* to achieve a strikethrough. For better control I'd suggest create your text in illustrator and import it into after effects.

Comment: @poor, please post as answer so I can mark as correct.

Comment: @poor: I didn't un-accept it: It still shows ticked on my screen. The answers was perfect, I was just expecting the one line comment above, but you went above and beyond. If it is still showing unaccepted for you, please let me know and I will flag the post for a mod to investigate it.

Comment: Ok, great! A bug or something :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Text control is very limited in after effects.** There is no functionality in the *Character Panel* to achieve a strikethrough at the moment.

---

#### Using Illustrator

For better **text control** I'd suggest create your text in **illustrator** instead:

[image]

and import the illustrator file into **after effects** afterwards:

[image]

**Note:** Editing the text in illustrator is still possible.

---

#### Using a shape layer

In order to create a **simple stroke** above your *Text Layer*:

1. Enable the *Pen Tool* (<kbd>G</kbd>)
2. With no layer selected, click into the *Viewer* (this will create the 'first point' of the stroke)
3. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to make sure that the line, which you are going to create is 'straight'
4. Click into the viewer again to set the 'end point'

This will create a new **Shape Layer**. If the layer is selected you can adjust the 'stoke color' and the 'thickness' in the *Tool Bar*:

[image]

Another way is to roll out the *Properties of the layer* by clicking on the tiny triangle <kbd>></kbd> left beside the layers name, go to *Contents > Shape(Number) > Stroke(Number)* to adjust the 'color' and the 'width'.

---

However a shape layer provides **much more control in terms of animation**:

1. Add a **Trim Paths** property
2. Create a first keyframe by clicking on the *stopwatch* of the `End` value and set it to `0`
3. Move a few frames forward
4. Create a second keyframe and set `End` value to `100`

[image]

Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/how-to-use-after-effects-trim-path-with-an-illustrator-path/49975#49975

#### Result

[image]